# PC fan DC adapter power requirement?

Tags: power, dc, adapter, brushless-dc-motor, fan

I just bought a 120mm deep cool fan with a rating of 12v, 0.07A (70 mA)= 0.84watts

Currently I only have a 12v 2.5A (2500mA) DC adapter.

I'm a complete noob in electricals...so the question is-

Can i use that adapter to power my fan?..is the power too high and will it burn the circuitry inside the fan...or is it ok to use that adapter.
Should I buy another adapter that matches the ratings of the Fan?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's ok - the fan will only draw what current it needs. It's the voltage that's important and they are both 12V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry as cooler will use as much current it needs. That 2500mAmps is the biggest current which source can provide to load, voltages are equal so everything is okay.

Comment: thank you...i hope it will run fine like you said...i was really afraid because some time ago i blew an LED diode using a 3V 300mA adapter...i had also burned a 9v motor using the same 12v adapter that ive metioned